# Type script issue in grouping array elements and performing some logic

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array of objects like the below

```
[{name: 'India', language: 'Hindi'}, 
{name: 'US', language: 'English'},
{name: 'US', language: 'Spanish'},
{name: 'India', language: 'Bengali'},
{name: 'Japan', language: 'Japanese'},
{name: 'China', language: 'Mandarin'},
{name: 'France', language: 'French'}]
```

I am trying to generate an array out of it such that if any country (name) has multiple languages i am trying to display 'many' as language property.

in the above case the resulted array should be like below

```
 [{name: 'India', language: 'many'}, 
  {name: 'US', language: 'many'}, 
  {name: 'Japan', language: 'Japanese'},
  {name: 'China', language: 'Mandarin'},
  {name: 'France', language: 'French'},]
```

I tried using forEach loop but not getting how to implement this logic . since i am new to angular 2 and typescript.. can you please suggest.

Comment: "I tried using forEach loop but not getting how to implement this logic . since i am new to angular 2 and typescript.. can you please suggest."... show the code.

Comment: There should be nothing specific to Typescript here. As already asked, please show how you are trying to use forEach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty easy using `.reduce`

```js
var input = [{name: 'India', language: 'Hindi'}, 
{name: 'US', language: 'English'},
{name: 'US', language: 'Spanish'},
{name: 'India', language: 'Bengali'},
{name: 'Japan', language: 'Japanese'},
{name: 'China', language: 'Mandarin'},
{name: 'France', language: 'French'}];

var result = input.reduce( function (p,c){
   // find an item in  the result with the same name
   var index = p.findIndex(function(x){ return x.name == c.name});

   if(index == -1){
       // if not found already add to the result list
       p.push(c);
   }
   else{
     // item with same name already exists - update the language to 'many'
     p[index].language = 'many';
   }
   return p;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **forEach**

```
var arr = [{name: 'India', language: 'Hindi'}, 
{name: 'US', language: 'English'},
{name: 'US', language: 'Spanish'},
{name: 'India', language: 'Bengali'},
{name: 'Japan', language: 'Japanese'},
{name: 'China', language: 'Mandarin'},
{name: 'France', language: 'French'}]

var out= []
arr.forEach((ele)=> {
  var o = out.find(item => item.name === ele.name);
  if (o!== undefined) o.language = 'many'
  else out.push(ele)
})
```